# Select from panadas dataframe using multiple columns

Tags: select, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
              Date  Adj Close
Ticker                       
ZTS     2014-12-22      43.41
ZTS     2014-12-19      43.51
ZTS     2014-12-18      43.15
ZTS     2014-12-17      41.13
```

There are many more tickers than just ZTS, it continues on for many more rows.

I would like to select using both the Ticker and the Date but I cannot figure out how. I would like to select as if I were saying in SQL:

`Select 'Adj Close' from prices where Ticker = 'ZTS' and 'Date' = '2014-12-22'`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following should work:

```
df[(df['Date'] == '2014-12-22') & (df.index == 'ZTS')]['Adj Close']
```

Here we have to use the array `&` operators rather than `and` also you must use parentheses due to operator precedence

Comment: Actually Ticket name is row name

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import pandas 
>>> from pandas import *

>>> L = [['2014-12-22',43.41],['2014-12-19',43.51],['2014-12-18',43.15], ['2014-12-17',41.13]]
>>> C = ['ZTS', 'ZTS','ZTS','ZTS']

>>> df = DataFrame(L, columns=['Date','Adj Close'], index=[C])
>>> df
           Date  Adj Close
ZTS  2014-12-22      43.41
ZTS  2014-12-19      43.51
ZTS  2014-12-18      43.15
ZTS  2014-12-17      41.13

>>> D1 = df.ix['ZTS'][df['Date']=='2014-12-22']['Adj Close']
>>> D1
ZTS    43.41
```

Comment: Thank you, but my code seems to run quicker, 15 seconds, compared to 60.

Answer (score -1):

I've figured out to seperate out the Ticker into a subset dataframe, and then index by Date, and then select by date. But I'm still wondering if there's a more efficient way.

```
cur_df =  df.ix['A']
cur_df = cur_df.set_index(['Date'])
print cur_df['Adj Close']['2014-11-20']
```